# Opening a preference programmatically

Tags: android

In my application I have a PreferenceScreen with ListPreferences, and upon some user actions I need to open PreferenceScreen with already opened ListPreference dialog or fragment( if it's a TV ). I'm using android.support.v7.preference preferences. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = (PreferenceScreen)findPreference(getString(R.string.your_preference));
preferenceScreen.onItemClick(null, null, position, 0);
```

where *your_preference* is the key to the PreferenceScreen you want to open, and *position* is the position of the ListPreference in that PreferenceScreen.